# How to print strange string characters?

Tags: python

I have a list with names. Some of them consists of strange chars like ★ or ™. When I am iterating threw list, it prints just fine:

```
★ StatTrak™ Huntsman Knife | Safari Mesh (Battle-Scarred)
Souvenir USP-S | Night Ops (Well-Worn)
StatTrak™ G3SG1 | The Executioner (Minimal Wear)
```

However, when I try to print it one by one:

```
print a[0]
'\xe2\x98\x85 StatTrak\xe2\x84\xa2 Huntsman Knife | Safari Mesh (Battle-Scarred)'
```

How to solve this problem?

UPDATE:

Iterating:

```
list = ['★ StatTrak™ Huntsman Knife | Safari Mesh (Battle-Scarred)',
'Souvenir USP-S | Night Ops (Well-Worn)',
'StatTrak™ G3SG1 | The Executioner (Minimal Wear)']

for name in list:
    print name

>>> 
★ StatTrak™ Huntsman Knife | Safari Mesh (Battle-Scarred)
Souvenir USP-S | Night Ops (Well-Worn)
StatTrak™ G3SG1 | The Executioner (Minimal Wear)
```

However:

```
list[0]
>>> 
'StatTrak\xe2\x84\xa2 G3SG1 | The Executioner (Minimal Wear)'
```

Comment: What code are you using to print while iterating? Can we see some more snippets?

Comment: I got the oposite result. It prints fine when i print one by one and with unicode error when i print the whole list

Comment: I have the same result as @Pardoido You have to show us Your code to solve this issue.

Comment: Updated with code examples.

Comment: Well I'm not really sure what You expect. That's how the strings are stored, when You execute `list[0]` it shows You the strings with codes for special symbols depending on the string coding, when You run `print list[0]` it will exchange those codes with exact symbols.

Comment: Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem with your situation, I think you just need a little clarification. But first, you have 2 typos I would love you to correct:

1. `list[2]` instead of `list[0]`
2. `a[0]` instead of `print a[0]`

When you type `list[2]` directly, you get this output:

`'StatTrak\xe2\x84\xa2 G3SG1 | The Executioner (Minimal Wear)'`

That is because:

`list[2]` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  ↔ `list[2].__repr__()` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I mean you get the UTF-8 representation of `list[2]`. Note that Python  picks up this UTF-8 representation from the environment it's been initiated from and which you can check by typing:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
UTF-8
```

But if you type `print list[2]` you get:

```
>>> print list[2]
StatTrak™ G3SG1 | The Executioner (Minimal Wear)
>>>
```

That is because when you call print with a bystring Python convert to to unicode first. I mean:

```
print list[2]
```

**↕** (is equivalent to)

```
print b"'StatTrak\xe2\x84\xa2 G3SG1 | The Executioner (Minimal Wear)'".decode('utf-8')
```

Demo:

```
>>> print b"'StatTrak\xe2\x84\xa2 G3SG1 | The Executioner (Minimal Wear)'".decode('utf-8')
'StatTrak™ G3SG1 | The Executioner (Minimal Wear)'
>>>
```

Simply:

```
>>> a='★ '
>>> b='™'
>>> a
'\xe2\x98\x85 '
>>> b
'\xe2\x84\xa2'
>>> print b"'\xe2\x98\x85 '".decode('utf-8')
'★ '
>>> print b"'\xe2\x84\xa2'".decode('utf-8')
'™'
>>> print a
★ 
>>> print b
™
>>>
```